# Terraform create_before_destroy outgoing data

Tags: terraform, devops, digital-ocean

Is there a way to reference information from a going away resource for the upcoming resource within the same apply? For example, if I wanted to know what resource I was replacing within a resource.

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "droplet" {
  name      = "example"
  region    = "nyc3"
  image     = "docker-18-04"
  size      = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
  ssh_keys  = [...]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
     inline = [
         "echo replacing ${digitalocean_droplet.droplet[0:old].ipv4_address} with ${self.ipv4_address}"
     ]
  }

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

I omitted a bit of the droplet code, but I figured this should be sufficient. Let me know if I'm not explaining the issue well.

---

Alternatively, if this isn't possible in the same apply, how would I go about this otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with DigitalOcean nor do I have a playground to use. However, I have tried the following approach using AWS EC2 and achieved the desired result.

There may be a better way to do this (comments and contributions welcome!) but you can use a [data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/d/droplet.html) object to obtain the IP address of the existing droplet. Then as part of the terraform apply you can refer to that data object for the old IP address.

```
data "aws_instance" "web" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["HelloWorld"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0d8e27447ec2c8410"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  subnet_id = "subnet-1bb60f60"
  private_ip = "172.31.15.31"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command =  "echo old IP is ${data.aws_instance.web.private_ip}, new one is ${self.private_ip}"
  }

}
```

I then updated the IP address to .32 and the output was as follows

```
aws_instance.web: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
aws_instance.web: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
aws_instance.web (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo old IP is 172.31.15.31, new one is 172.31.15.32"]
aws_instance.web (local-exec): old IP is 172.31.15.31, new one is 172.31.15.32
aws_instance.web: Creation complete after 32s [id=i-0cf1ac2618be9d202]
aws_instance.web: Destroying... [id=i-0bcad4b6988f60976]
aws_instance.web: Still destroying... [id=i-0bcad4b6988f60976, 10s elapsed]
aws_instance.web: Destruction complete after 20s
```

This should work similarly for your droplet. Below is my attempt at writing the code for you, but will probably need correcting in places.

```
data "digitalocean_droplet" "droplet" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "droplet" {
  name      = "example"
  region    = "nyc3"
  image     = "docker-18-04"
  size      = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
  ssh_keys  = [...]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
     inline = [
         "echo replacing ${data.digitalocean_droplet.droplet.ipv4_address} with ${self.ipv4_address}"
     ]
  }

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using data attributes, ipv4_address:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/do/d/droplet.html

```
"${data. digitalocean_droplet.name.ipv4_address}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place where Terraform *guarantees* access to the old instance values is in destroy-time provisioners, but they don't have access to the *new* instance values, so to access both of them in one place would require tracking that information somewhere else.

With that said, you could get *something* like what you were trying to do this way:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "droplet" {
  name      = "example"
  region    = "nyc3"
  image     = "docker-18-04"
  size      = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
  ssh_keys  = [...]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
     inline = [
         "echo creating droplet with with ${self.ipv4_address}"
     ]
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
     when = destroy
     inline = [
         "echo destroying droplet with with ${self.ipv4_address}"
     ]
  }

  lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

In principle you could have the destroy-time provisioner write the IP address to local disk somewhere and then the create-time provisioner read it, thus giving the latter access to both. That is not a clean solution by any means, but should work.

Due to some implementation details of Terraform it may currently be possible to observe the old values indirectly via use of data sources or other techniques, but that is not something Terraform guarantees and so might change in future versions of Terraform.

Terraform assumes that a given configuration either manages *or* reads an object, and so doing both in the same configuration can lead to undefined behavior. If you do it, you'll need to be careful to explicitly tell Terraform all of the dependencies between the objects so that they can't be reordered in a potential future version of Terraform that may implement the graph traversal differently.